# Cant send more than 15 emails with Rails 4 and Amazon SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, amazon-ses

I don't know exactly why because I'm getting no errors, but I'm actually trying to send 71 emails and my server always stop to send them at the 15th. I already tried `delayed_job` (which only works when I manually tell it `rake jobs:work` but even this way only 15 emails are sent.

I don't know what to do.
All my massive code are built with the controller structure like:

```
User.all.select{ |u| u.projects.size == 0 }.each do |user|
    ServicesMailer.askforprojects(user).deliver
 end
```

When I user `delayed_jobs` gem the line within the each statement is like:

```
ServicesMailer.delayed.askforprojects(user)
```

and my mail controller is like:

```
def askforprojects(user)
    @user = user
    @subject = 'sometext'
    @message = "message".html_safe
    email_with_name = "#{@user.name} <#{@user.email}>"
    mail(to: email_with_name, subject: @subject)
end
```

I really don't know what to do anymore, could anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

When you first start using SES, you have sandbox access only - you cannot use it for sending to any emails that you have not first verified.  In addition, you have limits on the volume of email you can send.

I would guess that 15 is some sort of internal limit.  Log any warnings or messages you're getting and there will probably be an explanation for your problem in that message.

Comment: Im not in sandbox mode anymore and my email is already validated. My boundaries are already extended including max send rate which was 1email/sec and now is 5emails/sec. I dont know where can I get the SES emails, but Im preety sure that my app is sending more than 5emails/sec. I couldn't find a way on the internet to manage to control this rate. Then only thing I found was this delayed_jobs that until now at least was useless since it still just sends 15emails and I need to trigger it manually. Hope you can help me. Thanx in advance.

Comment: What does the mail() return?

Comment: Thats a good question... I dont really know how to extract errors from mail command. What I really know is that when in production it shows 'Email sent to xxx@xx.com' like 15 times and then it just redirect_to the end action. But I already checked the array that Im iterating and its fine. It returns so far like 71 items that are in fact users that have mails to be sent. So, in other words, I got no error at all.

Comment: Looks like you can configure the actionmailer to raise exceptions: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Comment: Man, im sorry for beeing so incisive, but I dont think you really understood that Im sending emails... the problem is to send A LOT of emails. In fact, by console I could manage to send by aws-ses gem instructions like 30emails with the same each structure. I cant do it by native actionmailer, but I CAN send many emails.... just cant send more than 15... again, there are any error output. It justs redirect_to the 'done' action after it.